# How would I store vertex, color, and index data separately? (OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, data-structures, opengl-3, voxel

I'm starting to learn openGL (working with version 3.3) with intent to get a small 3d falling sand simulation up, akin to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R3Ji8J2Kprw&t=41s

I have a little experience with setting up a voxel environment like Minecraft from some Udemy tutorials for Unity, but I want to build something simple from the ground up and not deal with all the systems already laid on top of things with Unity.

The first issue I've run into comes early. I want to build a system for rendering quads, because instancing a ton of cubes is ridiculously inefficient. I also want to be efficient with storage of vertices, colors, etc. Thus far in the opengl tutorials I've worked with the way to do this is to store each vertex in a float array with both position and color data, and set up the buffer object to read every set of six entries as three floats for position and three for color, using glVertexAttribPointer. The problem is that for each neighboring quad, the same vertices will be repeated because if they are made of different "blocks" they will be different colors, and I want to avoid this.

What I want to do instead to make things more efficient is store the vertices of a cube in one int array (positions will all be ints), then add each quad out of the terrain to an indices array (which will probably turn into each chunk's mesh later on). The indices array will store each quad's position, and a separate array will store each quad's color. I'm a little confused on how to set this up since I am rather new to opengl, but I know this should be doable based on what other people have done with minecraft clones, if not even easier since I don't need textures.

I just really want to get the framework for the chunks, blocks, world, etc, up and running so that I can get to the fun stuff like adding new elements. Anyone able to verify that this is a sensible way to do this (lol) and offer guidance on how to set this up in the rendering, I would very much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus far in the opengl tutorials I've worked with the way to do this is to store each vertex in a float array with both position and color data, and set up the buffer object to read every set of six entries as three floats for position and three for color, using glVertexAttribPointer. The problem is that for each neighboring quad, the same vertices will be repeated because if they are made of different "blocks" they will be different colors, and I want to avoid this.

Yes, and perhaps there's a reason for that. You seem to be trying to save.. what, a few bytes of RAM? Your graphics card has 8GB of RAM on it, what it doesn't have is a general processing unit or an unlimited bus to do random lookups in other buffers *for every single rendered pixel*.

> The indices array will store each quad's position, and a separate array will store each quad's color.

If you insist on doing it this way, nothing's stopping you. You don't even need the quad vertices, you can synthesize them in a geometry shader.

Just fill in a buffer with `X|Y|Width|Height|Color(RGB)` with `glVertexAttribPointer` like you already know, then run a geometry shader to synthesize two triangles for each entry in your input buffer (a quad), then your vertex shader projects it to world units (you mentioned integers, so you're not in world units initially), and then your fragment shader can color each rastered pixel according to its color entry.

> ridiculously inefficient

Indeed, if that sounds ridiculously inefficient to you, it's because it is. You're essentially packing your data on the CPU, transferring it to the GPU, unpacking it and then processing it as normal. You can skip at least two of the steps, and even more if you consider that vertex shader outputs get cached within rasterized primitives.

There are many more variations of this insanity, like:

- store vertex positions unpacked as normal, and store an index for the colors. Then store the colors in a linear buffer of some kind (texture, SSBO, generic buffer, etc) and look up each color index. That's even more inefficient, but it's closer to the algorithm you were suggesting.
- store vertex positions for one quad and set up instanced rendering with a multi-draw command and a buffer to feed individual instance data (positions and colors). If you also have textures, you can use  [bindless textures](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Bindless_Texture) for each quad instance. It's still rendering multiple objects, but it's slightly more optimized by your graphics driver.
- or just store per-vertex data in a buffer and render it. Done. No pre-computations, no unlimited expansions, no crazy code, you have your vertex data and you render it.

Comment: A few bytes of RAM doesn't seem like much, but if, say the player for the world I have in mind is going to be 20+ voxels tall than to render a decent size chunk of the world  this will have something like 16^3 times the amount of processing to do compared to even a Minecraft world. At this stage it may be too early to think about optimizations, but for what I eventually have in mind I don't see any reason why I should be insulted for considering such a thing from the start.

Comment: It's the opposite, that's the amount of processing you're **creating** by packing it on the CPU and unpacking it on the GPU. Your time would be much better spent culling invisible voxels than trying to "optimize" theoretical arbitrarily large voxel batches.

Comment: Also I didn't mention it, but shaders didn't have support for integers until very recently, and graphics cards barely work with them. Using integers in shaders is almost as bad as using branches.

Comment: Alright. having looked into this more and tried out some of the actual code for it I understand how much more complicated my original approach makes this, so I'm just creating a quad class that stores the vertex data of two triangles. It can easily generate a large amount of data just by specifying the facing direction and color of the quad I want to generate. For each chunk of the world I can just loop over the voxel data, generate a quad for every exposed side, and store these in a vertex of quads. Then I just need to pass that to the VBO; I do appreciate the help :)

Comment: That's pretty much the naive approach to Minecraft-like worlds (ie large cubical voxels, not to be confused with small voxels used for live characters). Note that what you're describing won't work if you add any kind of transparency however (glass, water, etc), in that case you have to hand sort individual faces in eye-space (so it changes from frame to frame as the camera moves), which will naturally lead you to aggressive pruning (otherwise all that work will require you to add a few more decimals to your fps counter, so you don't see a plain 0).